# How to display overlapping markers in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map that I have many markers and some of them are overlapping so that I can hardly find the way to make it click.
I found the mapclustered grouping markers, but I do not really like that idea, I need to see them all.
Is there any way that when approaching the mouse pointer to those markers that are piled then they can be "opened" in some way to then to do click?
I hope someone can give me a clue how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. There is a library that does just what I need. Called [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier).

It can be seen running [here](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html)

thank u George MacKerron